# Calling restfull service using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Im in the process of rewriting my php code and use jquery instead when calling my restfull service. I've come accross a problem, getting the " No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource..." error. AS I understand this should only occure if you call your webservice from another domain. This cannot be the reason here, as I am calling it from the same domain as i used to before.

My old php function looked like this

```
public function login($email, $password) 
{
    $curl = curl_init(LOGIN);

    $curl_post_data = array('email' => $email,'password' => $password);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($curl_post_data));
    $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);

    if ($curl_response === false) 
    {
        $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        die('error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: ' . var_export($info));
    }

    curl_close($curl);
    $decoded = json_decode($curl_response,true);

    if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']))
    {
        if($decoded[error]==false)
        {
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $decoded['email'];
            $_SESSION['name'] = $decoded['name'];
            $_SESSION['api_key'] = $decoded['apiKey']; 

        }                 
    }       

}
```

My new re-written function looks like this:

```
$('#contactForm').submit(function() 
{      

   var formData = {
        "email"              : $('input[name=email]').val(),
        "password"             : $('input[name=pwd]').val()
    };

    var ValidJSON = JSON.stringify(formData);

    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        url         : 'http://xxx.xxx.dk/v1/login', // the url where we want to POST
        data        : ValidJSON, // our data object
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
        success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
          alert("success");},     
        error: function (jqXHR, status) {            
          alert("failed");
     }
    })
});
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Is the service on a different port ?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean .. the service has not been removed or changed. The only thing i changed was rewriting, to use jquery instead of php to call my rest service login function

Comment: I asked for the port because if your web page (with jquery..etc) is served from http://example.com/mypage.html and your service from http://example.com:8080/myservice you will get that error. 

And of course if your html page is served from a different domain...

Comment: is the html page that contains the jquery servered from http://xxx.xxx.dk ?

Comment: i have a domain with 2 subdomains ..The two subdomains run on the same port

Comment: sorry ... my service runs on service.domain.dk .. and my page on management.domain.dk

Comment: See that's what I was trying to get to :) 
management.domain.dk is NOT the same domain as service.domain.dk
(different subdomains means different domain !)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67398/discussion-between-redben-and-dth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means you service and your web page do not on the same origin.
The spec says same origin means :

- Same scheme (http / https )
- Same host (which is not the same in your case, sub1.host.com and sub2.host.com are just not the same host)
- Same port

More details can be found in the wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

So If you do not have access to the service code/can't add header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`
Then you'll have to proxy the service through your php :

webpage/jquery ==> php ==> your-service

Comment: note also that you can proxy it without php code, a simple web server config (apache nginx or whatever you use) can do it

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

at the beginning of your PHP code.